# How do I properly create and manipulate checkboxes via javascript in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I'm writing a web app.  Based on certain choices the user selects, it dynamically creates a number of checkbox input elements.  For the sake of usability, they should be created in a checked state, and the user would uncheck the ones they don't want.

I have the code working fine in Firefox.  Unfortunately, I have to target IE 7.0.  There, I'm having no luck.  Here are the relevant parts.

This creates a checkbox in the DIV box with CboxBlock for the ID.

```
function InsertCheckBox(name, appfk)
{
   // Create the text box node.
   var tbox = document.createElement('input');

   // Set all the values.
   tbox.type = "checkbox";
   tbox.checked = "checked";
   tbox.name = "cbox";
   tbox.value = appfk;

   // Next, we need a paragraph element to place it in.
   var para = document.createElement('p');

   // Text to place inside P
   para.appendChild(  document.createTextNode(name) );

   // Append text box
   para.appendChild(tbox);

   // Attach to the CboxBlock
   block = document.getElementById("CboxBlock");
   block.appendChild( para );

}
```

In Firefox, this works right off the bat.  The checkboxes are checked.  In IE, they are not.  So I added another function to fire after creation:

```
function SetCheckboxes()
{
   block = document.getElementById("CboxBlock")
   //cboxes = document.getElementsByName("cbox");

   cboxes = block.childNodes;

   for (ind in cboxes)
   {
      box = cboxes[ind];
      box.checked = "checked";

   }
}
```

I found the stupid bug where getElementsByName wasn't returning anything, but this still changes nothing.  The text boxes are unchanged.  I even tried changing it to box.checked = true, like I've seen in a few places, but that still didn't change it.

Can anyone see where I might be making a mistake?  Is there some other way I'm supposed to manipulate checkboxes in IE?  Thanks for any info you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe IE accesses it as an attribute, not a property.

```
box.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: Works perfectly in IE here, I've been using this since a long time.

Comment: Okay, I changed it again, and this time it now works.  I'm not sure why it didn't work last time I tried it.  Thanks.